# Python Project with Multiple Modules with the same Name

Tags: python, module, package, distribution

I have two different packages with the same name, each with a set of modules and classes with the same names as each other but they are implemented differently. What is the most logical manner to  set up my package/module structure?

Right now I'm doing something like:

```
  Common
    utilities.py
    VersionA
      Package
        moduleX.py
        moduleY.py
    VersionB
      Package
        moduleX.py
        moduleY.py
```

I am requiring that the environment where the modules are being used, just set the path to point to the correct version of "Package".

On top of it, there is one module that both packages share! "Utilities.py". Now I am also asking the installer to add the Utilties.py to the path.

This is confusing, and feels like a hack. However, I can't figure out a better way to do it.

Comment: Have you considered using [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a globally accessible env variable which you will use to select the version (VersionA,VersionB). Then, in `Common/__init__.py` put:

```
import whenver_you_put_your_env as envloc

if (envloc.env == VersionA)
    import VersionA.Package as Package
elif (envloc.env == VersionB)
    import VersionB.Package as Package
```

Now whenever you want to use Package in a file you should be able to do:

```
import Common.Package
```

and you are good to go.